# Resistance and Resistivity

Tags: resistivity

How do I calculate the radius of a copper wire dissipating heat of 100mW given that the volume of the conductor is 20mm^3 and is carrying a current of 40nA. Resistivity of copper is 0.0000172.

Comment: You have current and power, calculate resistance. You then have resistance and resistivity, calculate cross-sectional area. You then have area, calculate radius.

Comment: must be a really long nano-filament I^2R=P, R=0.1/16e-20

Comment: Do you REALLY mean nA = nano amps. That's 40 x 1/1,000,000,000 A OR 40 x 1/1000,000 mA or 40 x 1/1000 microamp.  I suspect that you MAY mean 40 mA.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like homework.

Comment: Units and the number of zeros after the decimal point are both *kinda* important in engineering. Your resistivity number appears to have more than one problem. It is certainly not in SI units, even if the Cu was molten.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. It's not quite that easy.

Comment: @LeonHeller: So it looks likes homework.  So what?  Isn't it an interesting, multifaceted problem  which should be addressed respectfully instead of being dumped on the trash heap of your vanity?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the reference resistance from your question:

   $$R=\frac{P}{I^2}= \frac{0.1W}{40\cdot10^{-9}A^2} = 6.25\cdot10^{13}
   \text{ ohms} $$
2. Start out with a 20 cubic millimeter right circular cylinder of copper and
   set its radius to 1mm.
3. Get the cylinder's length:

   $$ l =\frac{V}{\pi\ r^2} =\frac{ 20mm3}{3.14 \times1mm2} = 6.369
   \text { mm}  $$
4. Get the cylinder's cross-sectional area:

   $$ A = \pi\ r^2 = 3.14\times1^2 = 3.14\text { mm2}$$
5. Get the cylinder's resistance along its length:

   $$R=\frac{\rho\ l}{A} = \frac{1.72 \cdot10^{-5} \Omega\ mm
   \times 6.369mm}{3.14mm2}  $$
6. Compare the resistance of the cylinder with that of the reference
   and if the resistance of the cylinder is >= that of the reference,
   stop.
7. If it's < that of the reference, squeeze the cylinder to elongate
   it.
8. Go to 3.

It'll take about 1 049 303 iterations and, at the end, the wire's cross-sectional radius will be about \$ 2.74\cdot10^{-9}\text { millimeters}\$

Just for fun, here's a link to the source code for a tiny PowerBasic program I wrote to do the grunt work,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0qfpmu2ukafxu2/Long%20wire%203.bas?dl=0

The executable:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/p11jl6yot0bhems/Long%20wire%203.exe?dl=0

and the output screen just in case you don't want to run the .exe

[image]

Comment: Oops... 1. is wrong. I'll fix it presently

Comment: Thank you very much for the interest you have shown in helping me tackle this problem. Am waiting for the fix.

Comment: @Mark.Wambua: My pleasure.  It's an interesting problem  and I think I fixed my solution.

Comment: There's still a problem in  explaining the solution , but I can't get to it just now... Perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: So a wire diameter of 5.48 x 10e-12 meters, which is impossible because the diameter of a single Copper _atom_ is  2.28 x 10e-10 meters - 42 times larger that the 'wire'!

Comment: I got stuck too @EMFields. I will really appreciate.

Comment: @BruceAbbott: Unless I made a mistake somewhere along the line, you've shown that the problem was nonsensical.

Comment: Always verify the results you get. Plug the radius back into the formula's, and confirm you really get 100mW. I think the result should be: r=154nm (l=270km).

Comment: @peter: I think you may have missed the point,  which was that for a 20 cubic millimeter volume of copper  configured as a wire with a uniform cross-sectional area, there's only one area and length which will satisfy the dictates of the specified current through, and power dissipated by, the wire.

Comment: You got the right answer, but you sure took the long way around. Given that volume \$V = length\cdot area\$ and resistance \$R = \sigma\frac{length}{area}\$ (where \$\sigma\$ is resistivity), it's easy to combine them to get \$length=\sqrt{\frac{R\cdot V}{\sigma}}\$. This gives the same solution you have, and once you have the length, it's easy to get the area and then the radius from that.

Comment: @EM Fields: Anyone can verify for themselves that a cylinder with r=154nm and l=270km has a volume of 20 cubed mm.  
%pi*(154*10^-9)^2 * 270*10^3; gives me 2.0*10-8